# How to grep for VIM colour schemes that do not use dark blue?

Tags: linux, vim, colors, grep

I simply cannot see the ANSI BLUE colour in a terminal with a black background. How does one grep the installed VIM colorschemes for one that does not use that colour at all? I often SSH into different machines and Cygwin does not seem to have a colour override feature.

Note that using a terminal other than the Cygwin terminal is not the solution. I am a month on-site and cannot play around with this Windows box that I have been given. Otherwise it would be running Debian, not just changing terminals!

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `set bg=dark` would fix the scheme?

Comment: Thank you grawity, but I already do have that set!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the location where the colorschemes are stored, you can easily grep inside these files

```
cd /usr/share/vim/vimXX/colors
grep -L blue *.vim
```

Where

> -L, --files-without-match
>                 Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed.  The
>   scanning will stop on the first match.

Replace blue with the color you want to exclude from the colorscheme.

Comment: Thanks, but `-v` only seems to inverse match on line numbers. When using `-v` with `-l`, all files are returned!

Comment: @dotancohen You're right, see my edit